# How would you remove elements of a std::vector based on some property of the elements?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, vector

If for instance you have a `std::vector<MyClass>`, where `MyClass` has a public method: `bool isTiredOfLife()`, how do you remove the elements that return true?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I prefer remove_if

```
v.erase(remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), 
                 mem_fun_ref(&MyClass::isTiredOfLife)), 
        v.end());
```

[`remove_if`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/remove_if.html) returns an iterator pointing after the last element that's still in the sequence. `erase` erases everything from its first to its last argument (both iterators).

Comment: I forgot about remove_if() +1.

Comment: Well, we don't really need erase;  we use  because remove variations don't erase the elements, just appends them to the end.

Answer (score 6):

Using remove_if is the "right" way to do this. Be careful NOT to use an iterator to cycle through and erase, because removing items invalidates the iterator. In fact, any example which uses erase() as its primary method is a bad idea on vectors, because erase is O(n), which will make your algorithm O(n^2). This should be an O(n) algorithm.

The method I give below is likely to be faster than remove_if but, unlike remove_if, will NOT preserve the relative order of the elements. If you care about maintaining order (i.e. your vector is sorted), use remove_if, as in the answer above. If you don't care about order, and if the number of items to be deleted is typically less than a quarter of the vector, this method is likely to be faster:

```
for( size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); )
   if( vec[i].isTiredOfLife() )
   {
      vec[i] = vec.back();
      vec.pop_back();
   }
   else
      ++i;
```

Comment: D'oh. I forgot about that. It's even in bold in the page I linked. :o I've deleted my post, so no-one uses it.

Comment: Won't this rearrange the elements in the vector? Assuming that, for example, the input vector is sorted, the output vector won't, the last element will take the position of the first deleted element.

Comment: You might want to update your answer to not refer to Bernard's anymore.

Comment: Yes, this will rearrange the elements in the vector. That's good if you don't care about order (it's probably faster than remove_if, especially if the datatype is complex), but it's bad if you need relative order to remain the same.